# Fetching data from database into checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to edit my form. Currently, i am able to retrieve data into my input textbox but not the checkbox. Now when, i am inserting data, i check the items that i want to insert, get the ids and save into my database.

Now when i want to edit, i want to retrieve the items that i previously selected (the checkbox of which i selected should be checked ).

In my Json below, i am able to display the id of the food that i selected when i was storing. How can i fetch that into my checkbox back

**Desired output**

I want to have the selected items checked. As in my JSON, i have stored `chicken wings`. If i click on edit, chicken wings should be checked already.

**PS**: I am a beginner and my english is not really good.

**Controller**

```
     $item = Item::findOrFail($id);
     return view('edit',compact('item'));
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel label_container">
<input onclick="return items(this)" type="checkbox" id="" name="" value="" /> 
</div>
```

**JSON**

Comment: What do you want to display besides the checkbox?  The "name" field or other?  Add that to the question, what is your desired output?

Comment: @Nic3500 Please look at my desired output

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to see if chicken wings (or any other food) is set and if it is, output a checked check box.

What you can do is use an if(strlen($json_file['name']) > 0) to see if chicken wings has text or not and then do  /> Chicken wings.

Example:

```
<?php

if(strlen($json_file['name']) > 0) {
?>
<input type="checkbox" <? echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
}

?>
```

I realized that the name could be set but have another name such as chicken breasts instead of wings, you can do an if($json_file['name'] == 'Chicken wings') {}.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

this is one of my issue back then in checkbox, you can use tenary to check the checkbox if there is a value for that attribute. Try this one,

```
<div class="panel label_container">
<input onclick="return items(this)" type="checkbox" id="" name="item_checked" value="1" {{ $item->item_checked ? 'checked' : '' }} /> 
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)